# How to Disable All Rules?

Tags: vba, outlook, rules, disable

I get an error in Outlook 365 for the following line:

```
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
```

in code that disables my Outlook rules.

> "Runtime Error: one or more rules is in conflict. You must resolve the conflict before rules can be saved."

```
Sub DisableAllRules()
Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim count As Integer
Dim ruleList As String
'On Error Resume Next

'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

' iterate all the rules
For Each oRule In colRules
oRule.Enabled = False
count = count + 1
ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & count & ". " & oRule.Name
Next

colRules.Save

'tell the user what you did
ruleList = "These rules were enabled: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: DisableAllRules"

Set colRules = Nothing
Set oRule = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I think it was caused by certain rules that were no longer supported by Outlook and were highlighted in red in the Rules menu of Outlook. I deleted them and the runtime error  went away.